# How to set date of a datepicker in Appcelerator dynamically?

Tags: datepicker, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-alloy

I'm wondering how I can set the selected date of a date picker for ipad/iphone using Appcelerator?

I have a views/dates.xml:

```
<Window onOpen="setDates">
<Picker id="picker" type="Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE"></Picker>
</Window>
```

In my controllers/dates.js:

```
function setDates(){
 //Here I want to retrieve my existing picker and set the selected date to something else. 
 //For example: 
 $.picker.setDate(new Date("2017-03-03"));
}
```

Unfortunately, the above setDate-function does not work. I can still load the view and the datepicker will be shown, but it will still show the default date of today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the date in both Alloy XML file or in JS controller file as shown below:

**XML**

```
<Alloy>
    <Window backgroundColor="blue">
        <Picker id="picker"
          onChange="report"
          type="Ti.UI.PICKER_TYPE_DATE"
          minDate="2014,4,1"
          maxDate="May 1, 2014 12:00:00"
          value="2017-03-03T12:00:00">
        </Picker>
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

**.JS file**

```
$.picker.value = new Date(2017, 3, 3);

// or

$.picker.value = new Date("2017-03-03");
```

***NOTE:*** There's a difference in setting the default dates in Date Type pickers is that in .JS files, you have to use the **[JavaScript Date](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)** object, while in XML you have to use **[Moment Parseable](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string/)** date object.